# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am getting the error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. I am trying to delete all open form objects apart from the current one:

```
    FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
    foreach (Form form in fc)
    {
        if (form.ToString().Contains("_MainFrom.Form1"))
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            form.Hide();
            form.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can not modify a collection wile enumerating.

use     `foreach (Form form in fc.Cast<Form>().ToList())`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
foreach (Form form in fc)
```

to

```
foreach (Form form in fc.OfType<Form>().ToList())
```

This way your are copying to OpenForms collection to a new collection before start removing stuff from the original collection.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo This does not work :( I already tried that

Comment: @user1559618, sorry, forgot that `OpenForms` just implements `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`. You need to cast with `OfType<Form>()` as in my updated example.

Answer (score 1):

You cant modify the collection where you are performing enumeration(`foreach` for example). You should use here others methods such as `Remove` or use `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: "I'm modifying collection of Open forms by closing one of the forms while iterating forms and getting error that I'm modifying collection of Open forms while iterating".

Answer: either don't use `foreach` iteration OR don't modify collection during iteration. Otherwise they'll find out.

Most common approach is to split such operation into 2 steps:

- find objects that need to be added/removed from the collection
- act on resulting collection of objects

In your case:

```
var toClose = fc.Where(
   form => form.GetType().FullName.Contains("_MainFrom.Form1"));
toClose.ToList().ForEach(form => {
   form.Hide(); form.Dispose(); 
});
```